# account creation in aws from android mobile sdk

Tags: android, aws-mobilehub

I am just moving away from parse to AWS. I just wanted to allow the users to register themselves as a user in AWS DB. I also wanted to implement custom login.

As I as am completely new I have tried the following

1)Created an App in the Console by enabling custom user's SignIn

2)Enabled Cloud logic

3)Enable push notifications

4)Downloaded the package from the AWS Console.

5)I have created an Identity pool in AWS Cognito

Now I just wanted to know what I have to do next if I need to register a user to the app and make him Sign-In?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You now have to create your mobile backend.
Download - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample

And Follow the Steps given in ReadMe.
Quickest Deployment is using - Amazon Cloud Formation.

Make Sure you enter the right - **Developer Provider Name** & **Identity Pool Id**.

An Applicaton URL will be generated where you can register your user, either through web/mobile UI.

After this, 
Download - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo

Enter

1. IdentityPoolId & Region - in CognitoSyncClientManager.java.
2. DeveloperProvider & DeveloperAuthenticationAppEndPoint (URL Generated from CloudFormation Stack) in DeveloperAuthenticationProvider.java

Now Try Logging in your App with your registered User in DynamoDb.
Your Developer Authentication is Ready!